# Use Excel VBA to fix Word shape in position on page, exactly where it was pasted

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm currently using the following Excel VBA to paste 1-3 shape(s) into a Word document at the position(s) I need, however, they are not fixed to the position I need, and thus get moved around when I add more text using VBA.

Is there a way to add on to the following code, such that the shapes are fixed into their pasted positions in an equivalent manner to right-clicking on the shape and choosing to fix it's position on the page, not moving with text. While the code is flexible enough to do this same task a few steps later for a second or third shape, without changing the positioning of the first.

```
Dim appWord
Dim quoteWord
Dim wordSelection

Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
appWord.Visible = True

Set quoteWord = appWord.Documents.Add
Set wordSelection = appWord.Selection

...

Sheets("Quick Lookup").Shapes("QuoteProduct1Image").Copy
wordSelection.Range.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
DataType:=wdPasteShape, _
Placement:=wdInLine, _
DisplayAsIcon:=False
Dim wdShape As Word.Shape
Set wdShape = quoteWord.Shapes(quoteWord.Shapes.Count)
wdShape.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapSquare

**'!--fix shape1 in position here.**

 ...

'inserts more text and a table contouring to the image
 'product description text
 'With wordSelection
    .TypeParagraph
    .Font.Underline = False
    .Paragraphs.Alignment = 0
    .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
    .Font.Bold = True
    .TypeText ("Product Specs: " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quick Lookup").Range("SelectedFolds") & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quick Lookup").Range("SelectedCardSize"))
    .TypeParagraph
End With

 'insert Table
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quick Lookup").Range("Product1Table").Copy
 wordSelection.Paste
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 appWord.Activate
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

In order to fix a Shape to a certain position on a page, it's necessary to apply a `RelavtiveVerticalPosition` that is relative to a page element (as opposed to a text element). For example:

```
wdShape.RelativeVerticalPosition = Word.wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage   'or
wdShape.RelativeVerticalPosition = Word.wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
```

You seem to be using early binding, so the above would work. If you were using late binding, then the equivalent Long values would be 1 and 0, respectively.

Note that in Word a `Shape` is *always* anchored to a certain `Range`, usually the paragraph nearest to where the selection was when you pasted. A Shape will always be on the same page as the range to which it is anchored. That means, if editing causes the anchor point to move to a different page the Shape will also move to that page. There is no way to permanently "anchor" a Shape to a specific page.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this as well. I have a shape on the page I want to set it to "fix position on page" as you can do when you select the image within the document settings. I have googled the heck out of this and I have yet to find a way to do this in code.
Here is my code that creates a circle, and I simply want to have it not move when I add text or whatever else I do.

```
Set BBB = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeOval, Left:=450, Top:=0, Width:=100, Height:=100, Anchor:=Selection.Range)
    With BBB
        
        .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionColumn
        .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionLine
        .PictureFormat.TransparentBackground = False
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 52
        .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCentre
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Trim(Str$(OverallScore))
        .Line.Visible = msoFalse
        .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapSquare
        .Shadow.Visible = msoCTrue
        .ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset34
    End With
Selection.Collapse (wdCollapseEnd)
```